# Differentiation of Matrix Norm

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms

I would like to differentiate the induced norm $\|I - \gamma P\|_2$ with respect to $\gamma$, where $I$ and $P$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $\gamma$ is a scalar. How do I proceed?

[The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) doesn't seem to address this. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426356/differentiation-of-norm) seems related, but I think it's unlikely that the result generalizes to matrices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what kind of a matrix norm are you talking about. Vector based, Schatten, etc. ?

Comment: @ConvXET Vector-based, i.e. induced. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\def\pp#1#2{\frac{d#1}{d#2}}$
The induced ${\tt2}$-norm is identical to the Schatten ${\infty}$-norm (also known as the *spectral norm*).

The spectral norm of $A$ can be written in terms of its SVD
$$\eqalign{
A &= USV^T = \sum_{k=1}^{rank(A)} \sigma_k u_k v_k^T\\
\|A\| &= \sigma_1 \qquad\big(\sigma_1\ge\sigma_2\ge\ldots\ge\sigma_n\ge 0\big) \\
}$$
and its differential and gradient [can be written](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3602652/357854) using the first columns of $U$ and $V$
$$\eqalign{
d\,\|A\| &= u_1^T\,dA\;v_1 \\
\p{\|A\|}{A} &= u_1v_1^T \\
}$$
Setting $\,A=\gamma P-I\;$ yields the desired derivative
$$\eqalign{
d\,\|A\| &= u_1^T\big(P\,d\gamma\big)\,v_1 \\
\pp{\|A\|}{\gamma} &= u_1^TPv_1 \\
}$$